# Android: Alert Dialog return Object

Tags: android, callback, dialog, android-dialog

I have many text views in my activity.
For example if i click on the colour Text View. A dialog will appear with a list of colours populated from mColourArray. I should then be able to choose the colours and return the results in mColourArraySelected. The same goes for mAlphabetArray and mAlphabetArraySelected.

The problem below is when i try to assign assign the mColourArraySelected in the case statment it is empty because the resultList inside MultiDialog is not returned in the onClick event.

it wont let me change onClick  to return List so how do i implement a callback?

```
    @Override
public void onClick(View view) {

    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.textViewColour:
        mColourArraySelected = MultiDialog(mColourArray);
            break;
        case R.id.textViewAlphabet:
            mAlphabetArraySelected = MultiDialog(mAlphabetArray);
            break;
        break;
    }
}

    public List<String> MultiDialog(final List<String> list ) {

    resultList.clear();

    final String[] array = new String [list.size()] ;
    for (int i=0; i<list.size(); i++) {
        array[i]=list.get(i);
    }

    final ArrayList mSelectedItems = new ArrayList();  // Where we track the selected items
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(SearchActivity.this);
    // Set the dialog title
    builder.setTitle("multi select")
            // Specify the list array, the items to be selected by default (null for none),
            // and the listener through which to receive callbacks when items are selected
            .setMultiChoiceItems(array, null,
                    new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which,
                                            boolean isChecked) {
                            if (isChecked) {
                                // If the user checked the item, add it to the selected items
                                mSelectedItems.add(which);
                            } else if (mSelectedItems.contains(which)) {
                                // Else, if the item is already in the array, remove it
                                mSelectedItems.remove(Integer.valueOf(which));
                            }
                        }
                    })
            // Set the action buttons
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    // User clicked OK, so save the mSelectedItems results somewhere
                    // or return them to the component that opened the dialog
                    for (int i=0; i<mSelectedItems.size(); i++) {
                        int pos = (int) mSelectedItems.get(i);
                        resultList.add(list.get(pos));
                    }

                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                }
            });
    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.show();
    return resultList;

}
```

Comment: What class contains `onClick()`? What class is trying to access `mColourArraySelected ` and `mAlphabetArraySelected `?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice It is all contained within the same Activity class e.g MyActivity mColourArraySelected and mAlphabetArraySelected are class members

Comment: Can you show the declarations for all class members which are relevant to  your question? Also, it will help if you include the enclosing class declaration.

Comment: Small comment not related to your question: The `Integer.valueOf(which)` in `mSelectedItems.remove(Integer.valueOf(which));` is not necessary since `which` is already an `int`.

Comment: It seems to me that `mSelectedItems` and `resultList` are two variables for the same purpose. You can simplify your code by modifying it to use only one of these lists.